# Unable to join with criteriaBuilder using like, works with equal only

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I need a workaround into being able to use join in joint with like method. criteriaBuilder just supports join with the equal method, but not with like. For these cases, is there a work around?

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    switch (criteria.getOperation()) {
        case ":":
            String[] s = criteria.getKey().split("\\.");
            if (s.length == 1) {
                if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
                    return criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(
                            root.<String>get(criteria.getKey())), "%" + criteria.getValue().toString().toUpperCase() + "%");
                } else if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == Date.class) {
                    try {
                        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        return criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<java.util.Date>get(criteria.getKey()), formatter.parse(criteria.getValue().toString()));
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    }
                } else {
                    return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue());
                }
            } else {
                //I need a "like" here
                return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join(s[0]).get(s[1]), criteria.getValue());
            }
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

I appreciate.

Comment: Why do you believe the `like` doesn't work?

Comment: @ujulu "like" doesn't support join (in terms of arguments), just equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I managed the right syntax structure for using like with join. When using like, you need String as first argument, therefor, before doing .get put `.<String>get`

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
switch (criteria.getOperation()) {
    case ":":
        String[] s = criteria.getKey().split("\\.");
        if (s.length == 1) {
            if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
                return criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(
                        root.<String>get(criteria.getKey())), "%" + criteria.getValue().toString().toUpperCase() + "%");
            } else if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == Date.class) {
                try {
                    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    return criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<java.util.Date>get(criteria.getKey()), formatter.parse(criteria.getValue().toString()));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }
            } else {
                return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue());
            }
        } else {
            //I need a "like" here
            return criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.join(s[0]).join(s[1]).<String>get(s[2])),"%" + criteria.getValue().toString().toUpperCase() + "%");
        }
    default:
        return null;
}
}
```